# ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission returns -1 despite WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE granted

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

In phone settings permissions are granted. Phone with Android 8.0.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In my code this "permissions" variable equals -1 always:

```
int permissions = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 6 (API 23) you must also request this permission at runtime. This video may help: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Larry Schiefer for runtime permissions.

Considering to android docs:

[link 1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)
[link 2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java)

I made some changes to the method from link 2. Before doing something it checks permissions and if necessary asks user for confirmation, in other case it sets permissions forcibly.

```
    public void requestRuntimePermission(final Context context, final String manifestPermission, final int requestCode) {

        int permissions = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, manifestPermission);
        if (permissions != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                    manifestPermission)) {

                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Allow access?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        //Cancel
                        .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        })
                        //Ok
                        .setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                        new String[]{manifestPermission},
                                        requestCode);
                            }
                        });
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                // Permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{manifestPermission},
                        requestCode);
            }

        }
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
requestRuntimePermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 0);
```

P.S. requestCode parameter in requestRuntimePermission can be used to identify which of permission allowed in onRequestPermissionsResult callback. ([link 3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])))